# SSH reverse tunnel proxy can't open https traffic

Tags: linux, ssh, proxy, https, tunnel

I'm using two RaspberryPi, one of them is natted, and i've estabilished a reverse tunelling in order to reach the natted raspberry. This is the scheme

A <----> B (nattedd)

This is the code in B:

```
/usr/bin/ssh -fgNnT -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o PubkeyAuthentication=yes -R port_number:localhost:22 user@AipAddress
```

This is the code in A:

`ssh -p port_number localhost -D0.0.0.0:9999`

using A as proxy (port 9999) I can navigate to internet by B.
The problem is with https traffic, I can not open any kind of page.

I use FireFox with proxy setted to A (SOCKS v5), I get this error:

---

### Secure Connection Failed The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading. The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified. Please contact the web site owners to inform them of this problem. Learn more…

Somebody can help me to solve the problem?

Thanks a lot

Comment: "The problem is with https traffic, I can not open any kind of page." What happens when you try? Do you get an error message? What does it say?

Comment: I use FireFox with proxy setted to A (SOCKS v5), I get this error:

Secure Connection Failed

The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.

    The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified.
    Please contact the web site owners to inform them of this problem.

Learn more…